# Required: Variable Found: Value

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

```
public static int biggestArrayGap(int []a, int n)
{
int biggestGap = Math.abs(a[1]-a[0]);
    for (int i=1; i<n-1; i++)
{
    if (Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]) > biggestGap)    
        Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]) = biggestGap;
}
    return biggestGap;
}
```

For some reason, the second line in the if statement is returning as unexpected type– required: variable found: value. I tried == and that obviously didn't work. Any insight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You switched the operands in your assign statement.

Switch this

```
Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]) = biggestGap;
```

to this

```
biggestGap = Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]);
```

`Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1])` returns just an int value (no variable reference or similar). So your trying to assign a new value to a value. Which is not possible. You can just assign a new value to a *variable*.

Answer (score 5):

You have reversed your assign statement. Change it to

```
biggestGap = Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the value of `biggestGap` to the number returned by `Math.abs()`. Naturally, you can't, because that value depends on what `Math.abs()` contains and how it handles its arguments.

Perhaps you meant the opposite:

```
biggestGap = Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]);
```